# How do I automatically do a login with nodejs + passport?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, mean-stack

I have the application built fairly well, but I am required to login every time I restart the node server. I am looking for a way to auto log into a test account every time the server starts.

Should I built a new passport authentication method? Is there a way to use the method I currently have but just give it a username/password without doing the post method.

My app uses the req.user variable for all the login activities, is there a way to just assign values to it right away?

```
myroutes.js   
app.route('/login')
    .get(users.renderLogin)
    .post(passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true
    }));
mylocalstraegy.js
module.exports = function() {
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
usernameField: 'email',
passwordField: 'password'
},function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne(
        {email: username},
        callback...
```

I hope this is enough info to get a general idea of where to start.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're using a persistent session storage you could use a large expiry interval (days/weeks/months) so you don't have to log in each time.

Comment: I would suggest to create a request function that sends a post to your server everytime you enter the page or even when you start your server.